# C# Waiting for lambda callbacks to complete

Tags: c#, mysql, asynchronous, lambda, callback

**Summary**

I am currently trying to use a MySQL database library to execute a select statement and return it to an anonymous statement lambda in the fashion of a callback. This is how this specific (mostly undocumented) library handles requests. I also need to wait for the completion of this process.

I am currently trying to use an `async` approach, however it seems that the completion of task is asserted too early (i.e. the `await taskName;` is bypassed before the callback is completed, and so the Dictionary that is returned is empty).

I have tried using a completion flag method, whereby a boolean flag is used to denote whether the callback has completed and use `Task.Yield()` in a while loop before returning the task.

Below are two functions from two different classes. The first is from a Database class, the second from a Utility class (where the database class is being called from).

**Code**

```
/// <summary>
/// Asynchronously executes a select MySQL statement and returns a dictionary of rows selected.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="statement"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public async Task<Dictionary<int, object>> ExecuteSelectAsync (string statement)
{
    // Init dictionary of rows and counter for each row
    Dictionary<int, object> responseData = new Dictionary<int, object>();
    int i = 0;

    bool complete = false;

    DatabaseLibrary.execute(
        statement,
        new Action<dynamic> (s =>
        {
            // Take the data returned as 's' and populate the 'responseData' dictionary.
            Utility.LogDebug("Database", "Executed select statement with " + numberOfRows.ToString() + " rows");
        })
    );

    Utility.LogDebug("Database", "Returning select execution response"); // By this point, the lambda expression hasn't been executed.
    return responseData; // This is empty at time of return.
}
```

```
/// <summary>
/// Checks the supplied data against the database to validate.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="data"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static async Task<bool> ValidateData(string data)
{
    Database database = new Database();

    Task<Dictionary<int, object>> selectTask = database.ExecuteSelectAsync("SELECT fieldname FROM tablename WHERE data='" + data + "'"); // Excuse statement forming, this is just to test
    await selectTask;

    try
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> firstRow = (Dictionary<string, object>)selectTask.Result[0];

        if ((int)firstRow["fieldname"] == 0) return false; // data not valid, return false
        else return true; // data valid, return true
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LogException("Utility", e);
        LogDebug("Utility", "Database class returned empty result set");
        return false; // Empty result, presume false
    }            
}
```

I know that this code works, as a short while after the `Returning select execution response` console output is shown, a second line reading `Executed select statement with x rows` is outputted. **The main issue here is that a race condition exists. How can I ensure that the data is properly populated before being processed?**

Comment: I don't think shared the code where the race condition can be identified. What's inside the `execute()` method?

Comment: The execute() method is tucked away in a JavaScript library. This is where the statement is passed to MySQL and the response is handled.

Comment: Does `DatabaseLibrary.execute` return `Task`? If so, you should use `await DatabaseLibrary.execute(...)` to "suspend" your method until the database execution completes.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger I have given that a go, but the `DatabaseLibrary.execute` is determined at runtime (it is called via an export), and `await`ing it results in a RuntimeBinderException (cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need a way for the database callback to signal to your code that it has been called, and that the execution can resume. The easiest way to do this will be to use [`TaskCompletionSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1?view=netframework-4.8). It would look something like:

```cs
public async Task<Dictionary<int, object>> ExecuteSelectAsync (string statement)
{
    // declare the TaskCompletionSource that will hold the database results
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Dictionary<int, object>>();

    DatabaseLibrary.execute(
        statement,
        new Action<dynamic> (s =>
        {
            // Take the data returned as 's' and populate the 'responseData' dictionary.
            Utility.LogDebug("Database", "Executed select statement with " + numberOfRows.ToString() + " rows");

            var data = new Dictionary<int, object>();
            // build your dictionary here

            // the work is now complete; set the data on the TaskCompletionSource
            tcs.SetResult(data);
        })
    );

    // wait for the response data to be created
    var responseData = await tcs.Task;

    Utility.LogDebug("Database", "Returning select execution response"); 
    return responseData;

    // if you don't need the logging, you could delete the three lines above and
    // just 'return tcs.Task;' (or move the logging into the callback)
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it. You could also use a `TaskCompletionSource<dynamic>` (assuming the return type from the DB query is unknown) and use `tcs.SetResult(s)`. But that's really just a matter of preference.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Bradley's answer: there have been multiple ways created over the years for making something asynchronous. The older method was to use callbacks: You pass in a method that will be called when the work is complete. That's what your `execute` method is doing.

But it was found that makes confusing code, or ["callback hell"](http://callbackhell.com/) as some people call it.

So `async`/`await` was created. In .NET, it's called the [Task-based asynchronous pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap) (TAP), which allows you to write asynchronous code that looks like synchronous code, making it easier to understand what's going on.

By using a `TaskCompletionSource`, you are converting the callback pattern into a task-based pattern so that you can use `await` and make your code easier to understand.